# Product of the n roots of the unity can be $(-1)^{n-1}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to prove that the product of the n roots of the unity can be $(-1)^{n-1}$.

If i make $1^n=z$, z can be $ cis(\dfrac{k \cdot 2\Pi}{n})$ with k=0, ... , n-1

Now i need to prove that $\prod_0^{n-1}cis(\dfrac{k \cdot 2\Pi}{n}) = (-1)^{n-1}$

Comment: What is $cis$? Do you mean $\cos$?

Comment: @Ragnar $cis \theta$ is shorthand for $\cos\theta + i\sin\theta$, which of course also equals $e^{i\theta}$

Comment: @Deepak, Ah, thanks, learned something today :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}cis(\dfrac{k \cdot 2\pi}{n})\\ = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}e^(\dfrac{k \cdot 2\pi i}{n}) \\= e^{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2k\pi i}{n}} \\ = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k} \\ = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}(\frac{1}{2}(n)(n-1))}  \\ = e^{\pi i{(n-1)}} \\ =(e^{\pi i})^{(n-1)} \\ = (-1)^{(n-1)}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Apply [Vieta's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Basic_formulas) to the polynomial $z^n-1.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Use the fact that the $n$'th roots of unity are given by
$$
\zeta_n^k=e^{2\pi i \frac kn}
$$
and multiply those.